# the php code is not working for creating captcha

Tags: php

I am trying to display some random numbers as image in php. Actually im on my way to develop captcha in php, i know these are just random numbers but first i thought i should make a basic random number image so i looked for it and created the below code, but its not working, its not displaying aything except for the alt text that i had put in the img tag. Can someone please point out whats the error in the given code. Thanyou!!!

generator.php

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$text=$_SESSION['text']=rand(10000,99999);
$image_width= 100;
$image_height= 40;
$font_size= 30;
$image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
$text_color=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,'Sans-serif',$text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

captcha.php

```
<?php

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Captcha PHP </h1>
<img src="generator.php" alt="There is something wrong"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you link the <img> tag to captcha.php instead of generator.php?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Sorry when i copy paste the code here i changed the names. forgot to change the name in img tag. Really sorry. my bad

Comment: @AndrewWilson..no..no errors. just the alt text..(there is something wrong)

Comment: Enable error and warning output in generator.php and open this file directly in the browser. Resolve all errors and warnings.

Comment: They are already enabled. and there are no errors

Comment: make sure `'Sans-serif'` exists on your system. I'm seeing `Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font...`

Comment: how to make sure of that??? hmm..should i include a font-file here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you do not have the font available to be loaded.

You should be seeing:

> Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in...

as a notice as it did for me while testing your code. If not displayed, check your logs.

Download the "Sans-serif" font or "Arial" from any popular fonts website.

You would first declare it as:

```
$font = 'arial.ttf'; // I used this as an example
```

then modify your existing line to:

```
imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,$font,$text);
```

Sidenote: You may need to increase the width of the image, or reduce the font size, as it did cut off a bit on the right.

I found the "Arial.ttf" file here to test:

http://www.font-police.com/affiche.php?a=classique&b=sans-serif&c=arial.ttf

Direct link:

- http://www.font-police.com/classique/sans-serif/arial.ttf

Download it (to test) and upload it to your server so that it resides inside the same folder as your `.php` files.

**N.B.:** These are example links and working at the time of this posting.

Should they cease to exist in the future, simply find another font source, there are many out there.

Comment: There is still one problema. The random numbers appears in generator.php, but its not working in captcha.php.

Comment: @mastermind It worked fine for me. I don't quite understand what you mean though.

Comment: @mastermind Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Your system is probably not setup to "display" them.

Comment: @mastermind also make sure it doesn't have anything to do with include/require files.

Comment: I'm sorry man. there was a mistake in file name in img tag. So amateur of me. Thanks for your help though.. cheers :-)

Comment: @mastermind No worries, I'm glad it got sorted out, *cheers* and you're welcome.